# iOS PhoneGap as Subview(cleaver) get UIViewController in Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using PhoneGap as a subview (cleaver) based on the instructions here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS

I have a native UI on top of the webview.  The webview is added in the same was as the above link instructs:

```
vController = [CDVViewController new];
vController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
vController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
vController.startPage = @"index.html";
vController.useSplashScreen = NO;

[self.view addSubview:vController.view];
```

Now in my plugin I am trying to turn off part of the native UI, when a button in the phonegap view is touched, I use: `self.viewController` which is returning to me a View Controller of type CDVViewController.  This is not what I am looking for.  I need to access the view controller that the vController.view was added to as as the subview.  I have tried `self.viewController.parentViewController` also `presentingViewController` and others.

How Do I access the actual viewcontroller on the screen from a CDVPlugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
```

or

```
id currentController = [[[delegate window] rootViewController] visibleViewController];
```

I use the second one on a plugin I'm developing, and works fine (I'm using cleaver too)